# Checking if network folder exists with FileSystemObject does not work

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

I have a path like this "\\10.0.1.1\share\temp".

What I'm trying to do is to run through this entire path and create any folder that does not exists.

I use VBScript FileSystemObject and for some reason, the `FolderExists("\\\10.0.1.1\share")` returns False (but I know the folder exists) so the code tries to create it and throw an error.

The code works just fine with a local path "c:\share\temp".
It seems like `FolderExists` does not work with network paths, but I can't find any reference saying so. Does someone already had this function working with a network path?

Comment: Try `Namespace` method of `Shell.Application`.

Comment: Does access to the share require authentication? When I tested this the code worked with a public share, but failed for a share that didn't allow guest access.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Indeed it requires authentication for writing, I provided proper credentials and the code now work, but I still don't understand why guest account could read file but couldn't check if folder exists.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing two backslashes. Try changing

```
FolderExists("\\\10.0.1.1\share")
```

into

```
FolderExists("\\\\10.0.1.1\\share")
```